# Итерация по std::unordered_multiset

Tags: c++

При итерации std::unordered_multiset порядок элементов не определен (гаранитруется только, что элементы с одним хешем будут идти подряд без перерыва, так как такие элементы находятся в одной 'bucket'). А есть ли способ поменять местами две 'buckets'? 
В документации методов std::unordered_multiset нет метода, подобного методу splice контейнера std::list, нет и метода, который возвращал бы итератор на 'bucket' (как единое целое) с выбранным значением хеша.

Answer (score 3):

Про менять местами: Нет. Такой возможность нет исходя из идеологии hash контейнеров.

Про итерацию по bucket:

```
std::unordered_multiset<T> ms;
size_t N = ms.bucket(T(...));
auto it = ms.begin(N);
for (; it != ms.end(N); ++it) 
{
    ...
}
```

- [std::unordered_multiset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset)
- ms.[bucket](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset/bucket)
- ms.[begin(N)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset/begin2)

Comment: А можно по-подробнее про `bucket`?